# Load local xml file in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, xml, windows

for my app I have stored some data in an XML file, which is inclueded in the Project. Now I want to use the SyndicationClient to get the data from the cml file. But I get an error, because the uri is not correct. Here I'm creating a variable with the uri

```
var uri = new Uri("/assets/data/filename.xml");
```

And here I'm getting the error. So how can I read a local file in a Windows 8 app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131565.aspx) with second parameter of type `UriKind`.
Like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("/assets/data/filename.xml", UriKind.Relative);
```